# Filtering 2D numpy array by its unique value combinations

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a very large 2D array and I need to filter it its unique combinations, so something like `numpy.unnique` does not work. For performance reasons, I need to use a `numpy` solution.

```
>>> a # I have this
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0, 31, 39],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 32, 38],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 33, 37],
       ...,
       [39, 30,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [39, 30,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [39, 31,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

>>> a # I something like this
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0, 31, 39],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 32, 38],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 33, 37],
       ...,
       [39, 30,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [39, 30,  1,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Note that the order of elements does not matter;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do in fact believe that `np.unique(a, axis=0)` does what you want, after sorting the elements in each row. Thus:

```
a.sort(axis=1)
result = np.unique(a, axis=0)
```

Comment: Makes sense, I'll try it out,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import numpy as np
res = np.unique(a, axis=0)
```